# Bookmarklet to Convert Yahoo Contacts Table to CSV File using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, csv, bookmarklet

It is no longer possible to export your Facebook friends to Twitter or Google+ in the way it once was by using Yahoo mail- http://lifehacker.com/5824769/how-to-migrate-all-your-facebook-data-to-google%252B
Yahoo now (presumably forced by Facebook) tag all imported Facebook friends so you can't then export them.
I am wanting to find a way of converting Yahoo contacts to a CSV file including Facebook contacts, and thought the best way would be converting the simple print view (see https://dl.dropbox.com/u/95261/CloudShot/shot_21062012_153052.png ) to a CSV file.

Ideally I'd use a Bookmarklet and thought I could use a plugin similar to Table2CSV-
http://www.kunalbabre.com/projects/table2CSV.php

I created the following bookmarklet as a test:

`javascript:;var s=document.createElement('script'); s.setAttribute('src','http://jquery.com/src/jquery-latest.js'); document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(s); s.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript'); var t=document.createElement('script'); t.setAttribute('src','http://www.kunalbabre.com/projects/table2CSV.js'); document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(t); t.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript'); $('qprintable').table2CSV();`

This doesn't work because the table in Yahoo print contacts puts each contact in a separate table. I've got a sample here (I've changed the details to protect the privacy!)- http://pastebin.com/STuKmwQa

Ideally I'd be able to either download as a CSV or copy and paste. I'd like to use a bookmarklet as I want this to be easy for the end user and hope this will benefit all the people that currently can't export their Facebook contacts easily.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/GMmdg/5/

general selector format:

```
xtract('table.container-of-inner-tables table.child-tables');
```

concrete selector for jsfiddle, but it probably won't work with actual page:

```
xtract('body > table > tbody > tr:not(.qprintfoot) table');
```

Data extractor function, change internal selectors if necessary:

```
function xtract( rootTableSelector ){
    var rows = [];
    var csv = [];
    $( rootTableSelector ).each(function(){
        var $t = $(this);
        var row = {};
        row.name  = $.trim( $t.find('tr:nth-child(1) > td > b').text());
        row.email = $.trim( $t.find('tr:nth-child(2) > td > div:nth-child(2)').text());
        rows.push( row );
        csv.push([ row.name, row.email ]);
    });
    console.log( rows );
    $('#result').text( toCSV( csv ) );
    $('#json').text( JSON.stringify( rows) );
    // prompt('this is not csv', csv );
}
```

Untested, freshly written function to create csv, enjoy the options:

```
function toCSV( rows ){
    var newline = '\n';
    var fsep = ','; // field separator
    var quot = '"'; // field quoter
    var quotquot = [ quot + quot, '\\' + quot ][1]; // choose
    var alwaysQuote = false;
    var quoteIfContainsQuote = true;
    // omitted option possibilities:
    // - trimFields
    // - quoteStringsButNotNumbers(excel)
    // - putEqualSignBeforeNumbers(excel), etc.

    var lines = [];
    $.each( rows, function(){
      var line = [];
      $.each( this, function(){
          var s = this;
          var needsQuote = alwaysQuote;

          if( s.indexOf( fsep ) >= 0 )
              needsQuote = true;

          if( s.indexOf( quot ) >= 0 ){
              needsQuote = needsQuote || quoteIfContainsQuote;
              s = s.replace( quot, quotquot );
          }

          if( needsQuote ) s = quot + s + quot;
          line.push( s );
      });
      lines.push( line.join( fsep ));
    });
    return lines.join( newline );
}
```

### updated, full js http://marijnhaverbeke.nl/uglifyjs/):

http://pastebin.com/vCuVBUvE

```
javascript:(function()%7Bfunction%20e(e)%7Bvar%20t%3D%22%5Cn%22%2Cn%3D%22%2C%22%2Cr%3D'%22'%2Ci%3D%5Br%2Br%2C%22%5C%5C%22%2Br%5D%5B1%5D%2Cs%3D!1%2Co%3D!0%2Cu%3D%5B%5D%3Breturn%20%24.each(e%2Cfunction()%7Bvar%20e%3D%5B%5D%3B%24.each(this%2Cfunction()%7Bvar%20t%3Dthis%2Cu%3Ds%3Bt.indexOf(n)%3E%3D0%26%26(u%3D!0)%2Ct.indexOf(r)%3E%3D0%26%26(u%3Du%7C%7Co%2Ct%3Dt.replace(r%2Ci))%2Cu%26%26(t%3Dr%2Bt%2Br)%2Ce.push(t)%7D)%2Cu.push(e.join(n))%7D)%2Cu.join(t)%7Dfunction%20t(t)%7Bvar%20n%3D%5B%5D%2Cr%3D%5B%5D%3B%24(t).each(function()%7Bconsole.log(this)%3Bvar%20e%3D%24(this)%2Ct%3D%7B%7D%3Bt.name%3D%24.trim(e.find(%22tr%3Anth-child(1)%20%3E%20td%20%3E%20b%22).text())%2Ct.email%3D%24.trim(e.find(%22tr%3Anth-child(2)%20%3E%20td%20%3E%20div%3Anth-child(2)%22).text())%2Cn.push(t)%2Cr.push(%5Bt.name%2Ct.email%5D)%7D)%2Cr%3De(r)%2Cconsole.log(n)%2C%24(%22body%22).prepend('%3Cpre%20id%3D%22result%22%3E%3C%2Fpre%3E')%2C%24(%22img%2C.qprintable%22).remove()%2C%24(%22%23result%22).text(r)%2C%24(%22%23json%22).text(JSON.stringify(n))%2Cprompt(%22Select%20all%20and%20copy%22%2Cr)%7Dfunction%20r()%7Bvar%20e%3Dwindow.jQuery%3Bif(!e)%7BsetTimeout(r%2C100)%3Breturn%7De(function()%7Bt(%22.qprintable2%22)%7D)%7Dvar%20n%3Ddocument.createElement(%22script%22)%3Bn.setAttribute(%22src%22%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fcode.jquery.com%2Fjquery.min.js%22)%2Cn.setAttribute(%22type%22%2C%22text%2Fjavascript%22)%2Cdocument.getElementsByTagName(%22body%22)%5B0%5D.appendChild(n)%2Cr()%7D)()
```

Comment: This is so close to what I am looking for- thanks so much!
It doesn't work yet because of the nested tables. The parent table with class "qprintable" has many sub tables "qprintable2" where the name of the contact is in the first row and the email in the second row. Your example outputs the first contact only. Is it possible to extract all contacts? I don't understand the prompt "this is not csv"? The output obviously needs commas between each field and line breaks at the end of each line. Thanks again for your help- I hope we can sort this- there will be many many happy people if so!

Comment: My fiddle seems to extract all data from the sample. A bit updated output: http://jsfiddle.net/GMmdg/4/ . I chose not to implement any specific csv type, because there are so many subtle differences, like quoting quotes `,"\"" vs """"`, separators "\t , ;" etc. One correction: the `rootTableSelector` shouldn't select the container table, but the internal tables. Creating concrete selector is up to you, because I couldn't know why/when those elements get/don't get a given class, id, wrapper element, etc.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding. I've had a play and it works really well. I made a few adjustments to make it easier for the end user (remove content and output in preformatted text). The only problem is that I can't get it to work as a bookmarklet. However the code is quite easy to use by copying and pasting into the javascript console. To see the modified code see here- http://pastebin.com/BUdkXkRy

Comment: Will you host the script somewhere or do you want an entirely self-contained bookmarklet (except jQuery of course)?

Comment: Thanks so much for this latest version. I'm happy to host on my website if that makes it easier (It will certainly make it shorter). The only issue I am getting with the window that opens up (the one that says select all and copy) is that it's only giving me the first contact. I presume this is because it can't cope with line breaks?

Comment: Apologies for delay- I'll look at this tomorrow! It looks great.

Comment: It works brilliantly! Thanks so much. I added one line to the xtract function- `csv.push(['Name','Email']);` because the CSV file needs to have headers in order to be read by the various importers-  http://jsfiddle.net/iagdotme/kGPnb/

Let me know how I can credit you with this in my blog post!

Comment: I'm glad it works. If you want to credit me, just link to my SO profile, or simply link this question.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                •  • Welcome, visitor! If you came from the above mentioned (not yet existing) blog post, leave a comment here :)

Comment: Finally written the blog post- http://iag.me/socialmedia/how-to-transfer-your-facebook-friends-to-twitter-and-other-networks-an-update/   - thanks again for all your help.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up, this seems to be quite a lengthy process what you describe, I hope it will work for everyone :)

Comment: Hi. A number of people are commenting on the article that the bookmarklet isn't working on Chrome for Mac. It's certainly working on Windows. Are you using Windows/Linux/Mac and can you think of any reasons why this should be the case?

Comment: Manually copying the bookmarklet to Chrome (actually Mac/SRWare Iron, which is Chrome without google spying on you) is not working, because it cuts off the starting `javascript:` part which is required for a healthy bookmarklet. Actually pasting `javascript:javascript:javascript:javascript:javascript:javascript:alert(1);` pastes only `alert(1);` and pressing Enter on this just creates a google search (WTF?). Maybe this is the problem?

Comment: Thanks. It's a bit tricky to test as I don't have a Mac. I've asked the commenters to try pasting in the code directly from the raw Javascript. Maybe that will work. It's a bit of an odd bug. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 2):

With the given HTML, I would do this to generate the CSV data ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jefferyto/JPKet/)):

```
(function() {
    var a = $('table.qprintable2').map(function() {
        return $.trim($('b', this).text()) + '\t' +
            $.trim($('.first + div', this).text());
    });
    $('<textarea/>').val(a.get().join('\n')).appendTo('body');
})();​
```

If you are using a browser that supports data: URIs, you can use `window.open()` to save the CSV to a file directly ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jefferyto/JPKet/2/)):

```
window.open('data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(a.get().join('\n')), '', '');
```

Note that your browser will probably block the popup window in the demo fiddle; when triggered from a bookmarklet, the new window should be allowed. (You can also, instead of opening the window directly, add a `<input type="button">` to the page, that when clicked opens the window.)

**Update:** [This version](http://jsfiddle.net/jefferyto/JPKet/3/) will add a "Download CSV" link to the bottom of the page; when clicked, the browser will save or open (depending on the browser) the CSV file. This version should be used instead of the one that opens a new window.

Comment: Thanks for this. I couldn't get the 2nd demo to work- I just got a blank screen. Do you know what browsers support this? I am using Chrome.

Comment: @baritoneuk Did Chrome auto-save a file from the blank window? That's what my Chrome does (which is a bit annoying) after I allowed popups from jsfiddle.

Comment: If autosave doesn't work, `prompt('title', longDataString )` can be useful for copy-pasting.

Comment: @JefferyTo I don't think Chrome is auto-saving a file. I'm just getting a blank window.

Comment: @biziclop - not sure what you mean here- how would I use this?

Comment: Y'know, just try it: `javascript:prompt('Select All and Copy Me','long\ntext\nmultiline');`

Comment: @biziclop oh, ok, I see what you mean. Good idea.

Comment: @JefferyTo Sorry but this still doesn't work for me. I'm using Chrome for Windows, is this OS dependent?

Comment: @baritoneuk I doubt it's OS dependent. Which version of Chrome are you using? Under the settings for Downloads, is "Download location" set to a valid (writable) folder? What happens if you tick "Ask where to save each file before downloading"?